# How much stack memory does std::set(rb-tree) and std::unordered_set(hashtable) take?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable, red-black-tree, stack-memory

Considering when comparer, hasher and allocator are stateless, the struct of `rbtree` and `hashtable` should be:

```
template</*...*/>
struct RBTree {
    Node* header;
    size_t count;
    
    [[no_unique_address]] KeyComparer keyComparer;
    [[no_unique_address]] KeyExtracter keyOf;
    [[no_unique_address]] NodeAllocator nodeAlloc;
};

template</*...*/>
struct HashTable {
    size_t* buckets;
    Node* items;

    size_t capacity;
    size_t count;
    size_t usedBucketCount;

    [[no_unique_address]] KeyHasher keyHasher;
    [[no_unique_address]] KeyExtracter keyOf;
    [[no_unique_address]] NodeAllocator nodeAlloc;
};


static_assert(sizeof(RBTree</*...*/>) == 16);
static_assert(sizeof(HashTable</*...*/> == 40));
```

But actually:

```
constexpr auto sizeOf_set = sizeof(std::set<double>);
// MSVC (std:c++ latest) Debug: 24
// MSVC (std:c++ latest) Release: 16
// clang 10.0.0 (-std=c++20) -O0, -O3: 48

constexpr auto sizeOf_unorderedSet = sizeof(std::unordered_set<double>);
// MSVC (std:c++ latest) Debug: 80
// MSVC (std:c++ latest) Release: 64
// clang 10.0.0 (-std=c++20) -O0, -O3: 56
```

For `rbtree`, result of MSVC (release) meets my expectation. (But why 48 for clang???)
For `hashtable`, I'm totally confused...

I wonder if I had miss something necessary...

Comment: if it really matters to you, you can look at the implementation

Comment: clang is the compiler. the standard library is not a part of clang. with libc++, `sizeof(set)` is 24. With libstdc++ it is 48 because this implementation keeps a `Node` rather than a `Node*`. Neither implementation uses `[[no_unique_address]]` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thanks.